# list all tables in a database with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have looked around and still can't find how to list all my tables in a database. is it possible with MySQLi?

Thanks.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display all table names from particular mysql database in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467290/how-to-display-all-table-names-from-particular-mysql-database-in-php)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many ways.

```
SHOW TABLES
```

Is the most simple SQL statement for doing that. You can also take a look at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` if you want to have more details or do some filtering or such.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'your_database';
```

Comment: what are INFORMATION_SCHEMA and TABLE_SCHEMA??

Answer (score 17):

Using PHP 5.5 or later, a simple solution is using PHP's built-in [array_column()](https://www.php.net/array_column) function.

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
$listdbtables = array_column($link->query('SHOW TABLES')->fetch_all(),0);
```

Answer (score 11):

I'd try something like:

```
function get_tables()
{
  $tableList = array();
  $res = mysqli_query($this->conn,"SHOW TABLES");
  while($cRow = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
    $tableList[] = $cRow[0];
  }
  return $tableList;
}
```

Comment: The provided link 404s.

Comment: Updated link: https://devzone.zend.com/13/php-101-part-8-databases-and-other-animals_part-2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "domain_root", "##pwd", "domain_DBname");

$query = mysqli_query($link, "SHOW TABLES IN domain_DBname");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo "<b>Amount of tables: ".$numrows." and their names:</b>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row[0]." ";
}
```

Comment: Please explain what new information you are adding here

Comment: The above solution :Using PHP 5.5 or later..." did not work for me so I created this one. if the solution is incorrect give me a shout

Comment: Isn't yours the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703159/1839439?

Comment: Please explain your answer and maybe it will be useful. At the moment I don't know what I mean to learn from this piece of code

Comment: This uses the MySQLi class (procedural type) without any additional funtions.

Comment: So do other answers. Please use [edit] link and explain what your answer is trying to teach us. Code only answers are not very helpful if we can't learn from it.

Answer (score -1):

here is little example

```
class database {
    public $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,
                                           DBUSER,
                                           DBPASS,
                                           DBNAME) or 
        die('Database Connection Error: '.mysqli_connect_error());  
    }

    public function close_database() { 
        return mysqli_close($this->connection); 
    }
    public function query($query) {
        $query = mysqli_query($this->connection ,$query) or die($this->show_errors('Query Execution Error: '.mysqli_error($this->connection),'E'));
        return $query;  
    }
    public function fetch_assoc($query) {
        $query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
        return $query;  
    }
}

$db = new database();
$query = $db->query("SHOW TABLES FROM DATABASENAME");
$db->fetch_assoc($query);
```

Comment: Instead of creating this class as a wrapper just to use procedural functions, you should just use the MySQLi class.