# How to display all table names from particular mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display all table names in my database. This is my code:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'nucleus');
$db=new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
$query = $db->prepare('SHOW TABLES FROM `nucleus`');
$query->execute();
while($rows = $query->fetch()){
     echo " $rows";
}
?>
```

All it is displaying `1` for every entry, I don't know why. Any solution for this?

Comment: Please edit to improve formatting (the "quote" format is wrong for the body of your question and the readability of your code could improve by being more compact).

Comment: Thats because you did not bind your results. look at the manual example http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: yeah I did,I got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All it is displaying 1 for every entry, I don't know why

[fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) returns a boolean, therefore your result of `1`. It will return `true` every time it finds a row.

You need to use [bind_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) to bind the result to a variable that you can reference for each row.

```
$stmt->prepare("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema=?")
$stmt->bind_param('s', 'YOUR_DB_NAME');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($table);
$stmt->store_result();
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $table;
}
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 7):

To get the name of all tables use:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables;
```

To get the name of the tables from a specific database use:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='<your_database_name>';
```

For more details see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Comment: I got an easier version :) ,Thanks anyways

Comment: This is answering a different question.

Answer (score 1):

So, anyone looking for possible answer, here it is:

```
<?php
$query = $db->prepare('SHOW TABLES FROM `databasename`');
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($tables);
while( $query->fetch()){
         echo " $tables";
}
?>
```

Comment: The answer is that `$rows` is an array, not a string. `echo $rows['TABLES'];`... or output `$rows` and see what the index is.

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS
```

if the connection already made, no need to mention the db name

Answer (score 0):

I did a complete solution working, there are two ways to get SQL results, I preferred precedence to get results, $ROW will receive array data to show:

```
    <?php 

        $connection=conectadb();
        $sql = 'SHOW TABLES FROM pmsai';

        $result = $connection->query($sql);

        if (!$result) {
            echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
            echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
            exit;
        }

        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            echo "<p>Table: {$row[0]}</p>";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);          

    ?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.